# p:commandButton is not working from 2nd click

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The first time that we click the `Apply Filter` command button, we are able to get the results (it invokes the Java method), but afterwards if we click the filter button again, it doesn't call the Java method.

```
<p:commandButton value="Apply Filter" 
           action="#{searchBean.filter}" 
           styleClass="buttonBlue2M marginBottom10   
           update=":searchFormId:dataTable, slaPendingId, actionOverDueID, notifyctnPndingID, ApprovalPndID, slaOverDueID, showAllID" 
           ajax="true">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Is this a typo: `styleClass="buttonBlue2M marginBottom10     update="` it should be `styleClass="buttonBlue2M marginBottom10" update="...` or it is the actual problem?!

Comment: @Jorge: it would end up in a `FaceletException` during displaying the page already, not in a command button which doesn't respond on 2nd click. So yes, this is just another example of a careless asker who doesn't bother about the quality of the code snippet in question.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly getting an error in JavaScript after the initial call which is causing it to stop executing. Try pulling up the developer console in your browser and debugging the error.